# Spline line is very curved, how to smooth it?

Tags: highcharts

A smoother line is needed (the line should rise smoothly and evenly), but the values ​​should not change. Is it possible to build a more straight line without changing the values?
Screen with explanations: http://prntscr.com/qudf96
And my code:

```
<script>
function reDrawCalc(gdata, gcurr, nums = 2) {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            height: 400,
            type: 'area',
            margin: [20, 0, 20, 0]
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: null
        },

      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            categories: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
        },
        tooltip: {
              enabled: false,
            crosshairs: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            dataLabels: { 
              enabled: true, 
              useHTML: true,
              inside: false,
              style: {
                fontFamily: 'Rubik, sans-serif',
                textTransform: 'uppercase',
                fontSize: 'none',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                textShadow: 'none'
              },
              formatter: function() {
                return '<div class="chitem-time">'+ this.x+'</div>'
                      +'<div class="chitem-val">'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,nums)+'<sup>'+gcurr+'</sup></div>';
              }
            }
          }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'areaspline',
            data: gdata,
            lineWidth: 5,
            color: '#f0c997',
            fillColor:'transparent'
        }],
    responsive: {  
  rules: [{  
    condition: {  
      maxWidth: 500  
    },  
    chartOptions: {
            chart: {
            height: 350,
            type: 'area',
            margin: [20, 0, 20, 0]
        },
      series: [{
            type: 'areaspline',
            data: gdata,
            lineWidth: 3,
            color: '#f0c997',
            fillColor:'transparent'
        }],
    }  
  }]  
}
    });
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to do it? And how to modify my code for it?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Notice that line is drawing from point to point. In the example which you have sent, you will need to change the point positions to achieve the wanted result. Could you reproduce your case on online editor with sample data which I could work on?

Comment: That's it: https://jsfiddle.net/p3nbsoq5/

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment current line shape is at it is because of the points positions on the chart. If you don't need to keep points actual positions the solution which you can use is to use the dummy data for the points and use the correct one in the dataLabels. See:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fshx3n50/

```
data: [{
  y: 5,
  z: 0.20
}, {
  y: 10,
  z: 1.40
}, {
  y: 18,
  z: 6.20
}, {
  y: 30,
  z: 18.00
}, {
  y: 50,
  z: 73.00
}],
```

I also changed the formatter function to display the z value in dataLabel:

```
formatter: function() {
  return '<div class="chitem-time">' + this.x + '</div>' +
    '<div class="chitem-val">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.z) + '<sup>REM</sup></div>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect)